# Why the For-loop does not terminates?

Tags: java, for-loop

Consider the below code:

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();
      for(int i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
       System.out.println(i);
      }
      System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - startTime);  
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
2147483643
2147483644
2147483645
2147483646
2147483647
16825610038948
```

I'm not able to get the value of `startTime` from Eclipse console, since there are huge amount of lines.

We call the above `For-Loop` as an `Infinite Loop` since `i` value is always greater than zero. Theoretically, the loop should not terminate. But since we use `int`, whose maximum value is `2147483647`, the `For-Loop` terminates when we increment `i`, i.e. `i++`, when `i = 2147483647`.

So I was assuming that, when we increment `i` when `i = 2147483647`, the value of `i` will become negative or zero, so the condition becomes `false`, and the `For-Loop` terminates.

So to confirm, I tried the below code:

```
int i = 2147483647; // Maximum value of int
System.out.println(i++);
```

So if my assumption is correct, it should have printed any negative number or a zero value. but instead I got the following output:

**2147483647**

**Here is my question/doubt:**

When we increment `i` value, when `i = 2147483647`, the value of `i` is still the same, i.e. `2147483647`. So how does the `For-loop`, in the above scenario, terminated without any error or exception?

Comment: `i++` increments after printing. If you do `++i`, it should print a negative value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should've been `++i` in your System.out.println();.

System.out.println(++i);

Your assumption is correct, when we increment `i`, when `i = 2147483647`, `i` becomes `-2147483648`.

Answer (score 2):

`i++` is different from `++i`. First is a [post-increment while second is a pre-increment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).

`i++` means

> use the current value of `i` for the expression, then increment it

while the other, which is the one you are looking for, means:

> increment the value of `i` by 1, then use it in the expression

Answer (score 1):

Following code will clarify more about ++i and i++

```
    int i = 0
    System.out.println(" before i++ " + i++);
    System.out.println(" after i++ " + i);
    i = 0;
    System.out.println(" before ++i " + ++i);
    System.out.println(" after ++i " + i);
```

Prints

```
 before i++ 0
 after i++ 1
 before ++i 1
 after ++i 1
```

So

```
int i = 0;
int j = ++i;
i = 0;
int c = i++;
```

In this case value of j will be 1 and value of c = 0.

Answer (score 0):

post increment `i++` increments the value after sout executes. try `++i` to see changed value.